# I need help finding a smart solution to shorten the time this code runs

Tags: python, python-2.7

2 days ago i started practicing python 2.7 on Codewars.com and i came across a really interesting problem, the only thing is i think it's a bit too much for my level of python knowledge. I actually did solve it in the end but the site doesn't accept my solution because it takes too much time to complete when you call it with large numbers, so here is the code:

```
from itertools import permutations
def next_bigger(n):
    digz =list(str(n))
    nums =permutations(digz, len(digz))
    nums2 = []

    for i in nums:
        z =''
        for b in range(0,len(i)):
            z += i[b]

        nums2.append(int(z))

    nums2 = list(set(nums2))
    nums2.sort()
    try:
        return nums2[nums2.index(n)+1]
    except:
        return -1
```

"You have to create a function that takes a positive integer number and returns the next bigger number formed by the same digits" - These were the original instructions

Also, at one point i decided to forgo the whole permutations idea, and in the middle of this second attempt i realized that there's no way it would work:

```
def next_bigger(n):
for i in range (1,11):
    c1 = n % (10**i) / (10**(i-1))
    c2 = n % (10**(i+1)) / (10**i)

    if c1 > c2:
        return ((n /(10**(i+1)))*10**(i+1)) + c1 *(10**i) + c2*(10**(i-1)) + n % (10**(max((i-1),0)))
        break
```

if anybody has any ideas, i'm all-ears and if you hate my code, please do tell, because i really want to get better at this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

stolen from http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/find-next-greater-number-set-digits/

> Following are few observations about the next greater number.
>
> 1) If all digits sorted in descending order, then output is always “Not Possible”. For example, 4321.
>
> 2) If all digits are sorted in ascending
>   order, then we need to swap last two digits. For example, 1234.
>
> 3) For
>   other cases, we need to process the number from rightmost side (why?
>   because we need to find the smallest of all greater numbers)
>
> You can now try developing an algorithm yourself.
>
> Following is the algorithm for finding the next greater number.
>
> I)
>   Traverse the given number from rightmost digit, keep traversing till
>   you find a digit which is smaller than the previously traversed digit.
>   For example, if the input number is “534976”, we stop at 4 because 4
>   is smaller than next digit 9. If we do not find such a digit, then
>   output is “Not Possible”.
>
> II) Now search the right side of above found digit ‘d’ for the
>   smallest digit greater than ‘d’. For “534976″, the right side of 4
>   contains “976”. The smallest digit greater than 4 is 6.
>
> III) Swap the above found two digits, we get 536974 in above example.
>
> IV) Now sort all digits from position next to ‘d’ to the end of
>   number. The number that we get after sorting is the output. For above
>   example, we sort digits in bold 536974. We get “536479” which is the
>   next greater number for input 534976.

Answer (score 1):

"formed by the same digits" - there's a clue that you have to break the number into digits: `n = list(str(n))`

"next bigger". The fact that they want the very next item means that you want to make the least change. Focus on changing the 1s digit. If that doesn't work, try the 10's digit, then the 100's, etc. The smallest change you can make is to exchange two furthest digits to the right that will increase the value of the integer. I.e. exchange the two right-most digits in which the more right-most is bigger.

```
def next_bigger(n):
    n = list(str(n))
    for i in range(len(n)-1, -1, -1):
        for j in range(i-1, -1, -1):
            if n[i] > n[j]:
                n[i], n[j] = n[j], n[i]
                return int("".join(n))

print next_bigger(123)
```

Oops. This fails for `next_bigger(1675)`. I'll leave the buggy code here for a while, for whatever it is worth.

Answer (score 0):

How about this? See in-line comments for explanations. Note that the way this is set up, you don't end up with any significant memory use (we're not storing any lists).

```
from itertools import permutations

#!/usr/bin/python3

def next_bigger(n):
    # set next_bigger to an arbitrarily large value to start: see the for-loop
    next_bigger = float('inf')

    # this returns a generator for all the integers that are permutations of n
    # we want a generator because when the potential number of permutations is
    # large, we don't want to store all of them in memory.
    perms = map(lambda x: int(''.join(x)), permutations(str(n)))

    for p in perms:
        if (p > n) and (p <= next_bigger):
            # we can find the next-largest permutation by going through all the
            # permutations, selecting the ones that are larger than n, and then
            # selecting the smallest from them.
            next_bigger = p

    return next_bigger
```

Note that this is still a brute-force algorithm, even if implemented for speed. Here is an example result:

```
time python3 next_bigger.py 3838998888
3839888889

real    0m2.475s
user    0m2.476s
sys     0m0.000s
```

If your code needs to be faster yet, then you'll need a smarter, non-brute-force algorithm.

Comment: how is this faster than his implementation?  I dont think brute force works for this problem(its too slow) ... but i could be wrong

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to look at all the permutations. Take a look at the two permutations of the last two digits. If you have an integer greater than your integer, that's it. If not, take a look at the permutations of the last three digits, etc.

```
from itertools import permutations


def next_bigger(number):

    check = 2
    found = False
    digits = list(str(number))

    if sorted(digits, reverse=True) == digits:
        raise ValueError("No larger number")

    while not found:
        options = permutations(digits[-1*check:], check)
        candidates = list()
        for option in options:
            new = digits.copy()[:-1*check]
            new.extend(option)
            candidate = int(''.join(new))
            if candidate > number:
                candidates.append(candidate)
        if candidates:
            result = sorted(candidates)[0]
            found = True
            return result

        check += 1
```